# SQL Query Subtracting Values from Two Tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables, demand and fte, that have department, shift and demand or fte. I need to calculate the need (demand - fte). What I get is a table with 9 entries. I've run into this before and for the life of me I cannot remember how I resolved it.

There is also a department table which I neglected. It only holds the departmentID & Name

```
select 
    dp.[Department], dm.[shift], (dm.Demand - ft.fte) as Need
from
    tblDemand dm
right join 
    [tblDepartment] dp on dp.[DepartmentID] = dm.[DepartmentID]
right join 
    [tblActual_FTE] ft on ft.[DepartmentID] = dm.[DepartmentID]
where
    dp.Department = 'screw ii'
```

**Demand**

| department | shift | demand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 23 |
| A1 | 2 | 26 |
| A1 | 3 | 21 |

**FTE**

| department | shift | fte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 26 |
| A1 | 2 | 24 |
| A1 | 3 | 18 |

Expected result:

| department | shift | need |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | -3 |
| A1 | 2 | 2 |
| A1 | 3 | 3 |

Current results:

| department | shift | need |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | -3 |
| A1 | 2 | 0 |
| A1 | 3 | -5 |
| A1 | 1 | -1 |
| A1 | 2 | 2 |
| A1 | 3 | -3 |
| A1 | 1 | 5 |
| A1 | 2 | 8 |
| A1 | 3 | 3 |

Comment: Not sure what happened to my tables, they looked fine in the preview. Any suggestions on how to clean them up?

Comment: You need to have an *empty line* between the title and the "body" of the table ....

Comment: tag your database

Comment: Why does your your example query refer to completely different tables to that which you have described?

Comment: Right joins are fairly uncommon. Are you sure that you have the relationships right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your join should be based on departmentid and shift :

```
select 
    dp.[Department]
    , dm.[shift]
    , (dm.Demand - ft.fte) as Need
from tblDemand dm
right join [tblDepartment] dp on dp.[DepartmentID] = dm.[DepartmentID]
right join [tblActual_FTE] ft 
  on ft.[DepartmentID] = dm.[DepartmentID]
  and ft.[shift] = dm.[shift]
where dp.Department = 'screw ii'
```

Comment: Thank you. That did it.

I didn't realize that you could do an 'AND' on a join. Learned something new today.