# Stored procedure cleanup

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is an extension to the question “SQL query subtracting values from two tables” [SQL Query Subtracting Values from Two Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69760707/sql-query-subtracting-values-from-two-tables)

The query / stored procedure works as is and what I am looking for is how, if possible, I can clean it up. As with the other post, I have four tables that I am doing calculations with. The calculation is as follows

```
demand – actual FTE – pipeline
```

This will calculate how many resources we need based on how many people are in the pipeline. The pipeline is the number people who are in the hiring process represented by `tblResource`.

**tblResource**

| ResourceID | DepartmentID | Shift | Supervisor | OfferDate | AcceptanceDate | ClearedDate | Name | StartDate | HireTypeID | Removed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | Rob Dietz | 2021-10-22 | 2021-10-22 | 2021-10-28 | Test User1 | NULL | 3 | 0 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | Alec Guinness | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-02 | NULL | Freddie Mercury | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 | Alec Guinness | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-05 | NULL | Brian May | NULL | 2 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | 1 | Alec Guinness | 2021-11-01 | NULL | NULL | Roger Taylor | NULL | 3 | 0 |
| 9 | 2 | 4 | Alec Guinness | 2021-11-01 | NULL | NULL | John Decon | NULL | 3 | 0 |

**tblDemand**

| DemandID | DepartmentID | Shift | Demand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 32 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 32 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 32 |
| 4 | 2 | T4 | 12 |
| 5 | 2 | T5 | 12 |

**tblActual_FTE**

| ActualID | DepartmentID | Shift | FTE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 39 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 45 |
| 4 | 2 | T4 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | T5 | 0 |

**tblDepartment**

| DepartmentID | Department |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Nails |
| 3 | Screw II |
| 4 | Screw I |
| 5 | Finishing |
| 6 | Packaging |
| 7 | Heading |

Stored procedure result:

| Department | Shift | Need |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nails | 1 | 0 |
| Nails | 2 | -8 |
| Nails | 3 | -14 |
| Nails | 4 | NULL |

Stored procedure code:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetTotalDeficit
AS
    SELECT
        z.department AS Department,
        z.w_shift AS [Shift],
        SUM(z.dmnd - z.fte - z.pipeline) AS Need
    FROM
        (SELECT
             y.department,
             y.departmentID,
             y.w_shift,
             y.pipeline,
             y.fte,
             [tblDemand].[Demand] AS dmnd
         FROM
             (SELECT
                  x.department,
                  x.DepartmentID,
                  w_shift,
                  x.pipeline,
                  tblActual_FTE.fte
              FROM
                  (SELECT
                       dpt.[Department],
                       rsrc.[DepartmentID],
                       rsrc.[shift] AS w_shift,
                       COUNT(rsrc.[shift]) AS pipeline
                   FROM
                       [tblResource] rsrc
                   JOIN
                       tblDepartment dpt ON rsrc.[DepartmentID] = dpt.DepartmentID
                   WHERE 
                       dpt.Department = @Dept
                   GROUP BY
                       dpt.Department, rsrc.[Shift], rsrc.[DepartmentID]) x
              LEFT JOIN
                  tblActual_FTE ON x.[DepartmentID] = tblActual_FTE.[DepartmentID]
                                AND x.w_shift = tblActual_FTE.[Shift]
              GROUP BY
                  x.Department, x.DepartmentID,
                  w_shift, x.pipeline, tblActual_FTE.FTE) y
         LEFT JOIN 
             tblDemand ON y.DepartmentID = tblDemand.DepartmentID
                       AND y.w_shift = tblDemand.[Shift]) z
    GROUP BY
        z.Department, z.w_shift
END
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clean it up"?

Comment: Make it more efficient, use standard processes. I am a hack when it comes to SQL and I am just curious as to whether I am using the correct processes.

Comment: The formatting alone of this is enough to be nearly impossible to decipher. It is just a wall of text. Then there subqueries after subqueries and aliases that make it more difficult than neccesary. (x, y, z is similar to button1, button2: give them useful names). And I can't wrap my head around what you are trying to do here at all.

Comment: I appreciate your frustration. This is how 'everyone' at my company write their queries; using single letters for the alias'. I always thought it was weird and difficult to sort out. I will try to rewrite it with readable names for alias' and see what happens. Once I get it rewritten I'll try to explain the logic, or lack thereof, of the query. I'm looking for industry standards for write queries.

Comment: Single letters is a not so bad, but they have to mean something, not just `x` `y` `z`. Basic formatting is an absolute must.

Comment: Why is there a shift `T4` and `T5` rather than `4` and `5`, and what happened to `5` in the final result?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a CTE - Common Table Expression to flatten out the SQL query.  That is the "With" keyword.

Instead of

Select ... FROM
(select ... FROM
(select ... FROM ...) C) B

Try

With First_Query AS
(
SELECT ... FROM abcTable
),

Second_Query AS
(
SELECT ... FROM First_Query
left join defTable ON (...)
),

Third_Query AS
(
SELECT ... FROM Second_Query
left join ghiTable ON (...)
)

SELECT ... FROM Third_Query

Each of the selects in the with statement can be used by any later queries in the with statement.

This lets you build out and test each of the individual queries in a much larger select statement/nested queries one at a time.

It also lets you rename data fields in the queries to make the following query easier by having a With clause query use the follwing query to allow "PayLevel" to be used instead of "lvl" in all of the queries
select LVL AS PayLevel from table x

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try and see if it is more readable.